# Open a WPF window app form VS extension command

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing my first VS extension.
so far i have the code to get selected text and display a message box or manipulate the selection:

the CTOR of the extention..

```
        private StringRefactor(Package package)
        {
            if (package == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("package");
            }

            this.package = package;

            OleMenuCommandService commandService = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
            if (commandService != null)
            {
                var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
                var menuItem = new MenuCommand(this.MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID);
                commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
            }
        }
```

The callback:

```
    private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selection = getSelection();

        var selectedText = selection == null ? "No text selected..." : selection.StreamSelectionSpan.GetText();
        string message = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Inside {0}.MenuItemCallback()", this.GetType().FullName);
        string title = "StringRefactor";

        // Show a message box to prove we were here
        VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(
            this.ServiceProvider,
            selectedText,
            title,
            OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
            OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
            OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST);
    }
```

now instead of `VsShellUtilities.ShowMessageBox(...` i would like to open a prompt window that display several textboxes and ok\cancel button..

I thought of creating another WPF app project and launching it from the callback but I'm not sure this is the right way to write an extension that opens a custom tool ..

so what is the right way to open a custom window with functionality from a VISIX ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own WPF dialogs in the VSIX extension. In fact Visual Studio is designed for that (since the UI is WPF).

See this article for further instructions:

[Creating and Managing Modal Dialog Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943166.aspx)